# Bootstrap CSS undesired overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm typically more of a backend guy, but I find myself working on a project that requires some frontend work. I'm fumbling my way through using bootstrap, and I find myself stuck on the following:

```
<div id="form" class="col-md-6">
    <!-- form goes here -->
</div>
<br /> <!-- multiple br tags do nothing, as long as col-md-6 is used above -->
<div id="image_container">
    <image src="myimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

I want a gap between the end of the form and the top of the image, but `col-md-6` seems to be resulting in there being overlap, and the image-div is vertically larger than it is on the same page with `col-md-6` removed.

Admittedly, CSS has never been my forté, but I'm hoping to address that soon. In the meantime, can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: col-* must be within a "row" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're not using the grid system correctly, you have to use rows and cols to separate your elements in your frontend.

[Check this link about Bootstrap Grid System](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)